# jQuery remove all $.ajax requests from $.ajax loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, bind

I am creating a page that a user can click a link and it will $.ajax load the content into a container div. The problem is the source files all have $.ajax requests of there own, so when a user clicks 2 or more links, it begins incrementing the amount of $.ajax requests and the container div is overrun with data. Basically my goal is for the user to click a link and it loads the requested page (and begins $.ajax refreshing from the ajax loaded source). And when they click another link it clears the old $.ajax requests from the previous ajax loaded content.

```
$(function(){
                $("a.text").click(function(){
                    $("#botscontainer").remove();
                    $("#botsparent").append("<div id=\"botscontainer\"></div>");
                    $.ajax({
                      url: $(this).attr("id") + ".html",
                      cache: false,
                      success: function(data){
                        $("#botscontainer").hide().append(data).fadeIn("slow");
                      }
                    });

                    return false;
                });
            });
```

You can see when user clicks link with class text, it will send an ajax request to a page with more ajax content (that is on an interval). So I need to clear the old "data" when the user clicks another link. I even went as far as completely removing the parent element and recreating it, but it won't remove the $.ajax requests from the data. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you need to be using setInterval(). Simply make the var that holds the setInterval global, and on the first page you want to load ajax content into, use clearInterval(var) to stop the previous ajax requests.

```
$(function(){
                $("a.text").click(function()
                {
                    clearInterval(refreshId2);
                    $.ajax({
                      url: $(this).attr("id") + ".html",
                      cache: false,
                      success: function(data){
                        $("#botscontainer").hide().html(data).fadeIn("slow");
                      }
                    });

                    return false;
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Abort the previous requests... Try this...

```
       $(function()
       {
            $("a.text").bind('click', Request);
       });

       function Request()
            {
                /* I put try catch so that if the xhr object doesn't exist it won't throw error */
                try{
                xhr.abort();
                }
                catch(e){}
                xhr = null;
                xhr = $.ajax({
                  url: $(this).attr("id") + ".html",
                  cache: false,
                  success: function(data){
                    $("#botscontainer").hide().html(data).fadeIn("slow");
                  }
                }
                return false;
            }
```

Bind links to just one function... You are basically assigning them to their own AJAX.

Comment: Same result. I originally had that, then changed it to append thinking that .remove() might not work with .html(). Either way it still is requesting all $.ajax requests from other "clicks". The content replaces fine, but the $.ajax requests that are on an interval don't stop

Comment: @Ed Why do you have to run the function simultaneously using interval?

Comment: It is the url: that the $.ajax loads that has content on an interval. The loaded content pulls data from a query and refreshes the container every 4 seconds so new data will show up.

Comment: Same issue. The .html() has no problem replacing the frontend content (i.e. text), but for some reason it won't stop the interval ajax requests from previous .click() events

Comment: @Ed - So, you basically want to cancel previous requests? So that it will stop populating your container, right? Try my revised answer.

Comment: Right, I want to cancel the previous request so the previous request will stop populating my container, and teh new request will begin populating my container. That doesn't seem to be working. I just want to clarify the Interval requests are being called from the .click() $.ajax request. so the Interval requests are stored in function(data)

Comment: @Ed - You are assigning the links to different request functions, do you really need to do that? If not, try my revised answer.

Comment: @EdR let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1168/discussion-between-domanokz-and-ed-r)

Answer (score 0):

You could cancel the request

```
var x;//in the outer scope of ajax call

x.abort();
x = $.ajax(params);
```